# accept more than one answer

Tags: feature-request

In some questions that I have asked, more than one person has contributed equally great answers but unfortunately i wasn't allowed to accept both answers. Could the rule possibly be amended to allow  such an action? I know i could upvote more than one answer, and i did do that. Problem arose when i had accepted a very good answer, then later came an even better answer and i ticked the latter- it looks as if i have unaccepted the former while I didn't mean to! Please advise. Thanks in anticipation :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upvotes are for rewarding useful answers, and can be applied to as many answers as you wish.

The express purpose of the Accepted answer is to single it out as ***the*** answer that most helped you.  If it's a toss-up, you don't have to accept either answer.

Some people also like to, after the fact, offer and reward a bounty to answers that were exceptionally good.

Comment: And the bounty can either go to the top answer, or **any other that you choose**